# Set an active class on <li> with javascript not working as it should

Tags: php, javascript

I have a little problem getting the javascript to set an active class on my "li" menu items.

The menu is constructed in php like below.

```
<nav class="categoriesMenu">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs categories">
<?php
        $i=0;
            foreach($categories as $k=>$v){
            $space = array(" ");
            $normalizedCategory = str_replace($space, "", $k);
            echo "<li id='id$normalizedCategory'>";
                 if($i==0){
                    echo "<a href='#'>$k</a>";
                 }else{
                    echo "<a href='#'>$k</a>";
                 }
                 $i++;
              echo "</li>";
           } ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And i have the following javascript setting the active classes based on clicks but i cant get it to set the active class on "li" only on an "a" tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var selectCategory=function(id){
        var ref=id.replace(' ','');
        var classSelector=ref.replace(' ','');
        $("nav > ul.categories > li").removeClass("active");
        $("#"+ref+" > li").addClass("active");
        $('nav > ul.subCategories > li').hide();
        $('nav > ul.subCategories > li.'+classSelector).show();
}

$('nav > ul.subCategories > li').click(function(){
               if(!$(this).children('li').hasClass("active")){
                 window[$(this).attr('title')]();
               }
               $('nav > ul.subCategories > li').removeClass("active");
               $(this).children().addClass("active")
           });

$('nav > ul.categories > li').click(function(){
            var reference=$(this).attr('id');
            selectCategory(reference);
})

var firstCat=$('nav > ul.subCategories > li:first').attr('class');
selectCategory(firstCat);

})
```

The menu gets rendered in this format

```
 <div class="navigation">
 <nav class="categoriesMenu">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs categories">
 <li id='idManagement'>
      <a href='#'>Management</a>
 </li>
 <li id='idReports'>
      <a href='#'>Reports</a>
 </li>
 <li id='idUsers'>
      <a href='#'>Users</a>
 </li>
 <li id='idAdministration'>
     <a href='#'>Administration</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
</nav>

 <nav class="subCategoriesMenu">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills subCategories">
 <li class='idManagement' id='idManagementRequests' title='RequestsInterface'>
      <a>Requests</a>
 </li>
 <li class='idManagement' id='idManagementTeamActivity' title='ActivityInterface'>
 <a>Team Activity</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: The `.children()` function only gets you **immediate** descendants.  Do your `<li>` elements really contain other `<li>` elements as immediate descendants? (I'm pretty sure they can't.)

Comment: Trying to figure out what you are doing. You menu looks only one level deep. So if you click on the li, what other li children are there to get? Are you trying to get their siblings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var selectCategory=function(id){
    var ref=id.replace(' ','');
    var classSelector=ref.replace(' ','');
    $("nav > ul.categories > li").removeClass("active");
    $("#"+ref).addClass("active");
    $('nav > ul.subCategories > li').hide();
    $('nav > ul.subCategories > li.'+classSelector).show();
}
$('ul.subCategories li').click(function(){
    /*if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
        window[$(this).attr('title')]();
    }*/
    $('nav > ul.subCategories > li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('nav > ul.categories > li').click(function(
    var reference=$(this).attr('id');
    selectCategory(reference);
});

var firstCat=$('nav > ul.subCategories > li:first').attr('class');
selectCategory(firstCat);
```

Does this fiddle do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/nzjhK/32

Comment: that works for the menu's sub items 'ul.subCategories' but not for the menu items 'ul.categories'.

Comment: See my edit with attached fiddle. Are you trying to make both submenu li have the active class? If so, use the code I have, if not, remove the `$('li.'+ref).addClass('active');` line. Also, your `window[$(this).attr(title)]();` is not valid code as far as I know unless it's a plugin of sorts. It didn't work in Fiddle anyway.

Comment: like i said in the previous comment that in that case it works to highlight the menu subitems but not the menu items. Like in fiddle the management and all the menu itemsshould be highlighted when clicked.

Comment: Oh... there http://jsfiddle.net/nzjhK/32/  All you needed to do was change the id selector in your function. I edited the full code.

Comment: Great! it was late and i was tired and did not see that little change. Thanks a lot